# Copying data from one sheet to another sheet using paste and insert rows

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm new to Excel VBA and I'm given a project that requires to copy data from sheet 1 to new workbook. The problems are with the copy, paste and insert new rows. (There are two subroutines but the second subroutine is about the same and it's required, please forgive), Thanks.

```
Sub CopyInfo()
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    wb1.Sheets("dataform").Range("L2:N2").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("A2:C27").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("A2:C28").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


    wb1.Sheets("dataform").Range("B2:B28").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("D2").Insert Shift:=xlDown

    wb1.Sheets("dataform").Range("D2:D28").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("F2").Insert Shift:=xlDown

    update

    wb1.Sheets("Setlist").Range("G2").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("E2:E27").Rows("1:27").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("E2:E28").Paste1Special

   wb2.Sheets(shtname).Columns().AutoFit

Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub


Sub update()

    wb1.Sheets("dataform").Range("D2:D28").Copy
    wb1.Sheets("dataform").Range("E2:E28").PasteSpecial
    wb1.Sheets("dataform").Range("F2:F28").PasteSpecial

    wb1.Sheets("dataform").Range("F2:F28").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("G2").Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

The program requires from current workbook sheet 1 copies to another workbook. The first workbook sheets 1 will have new rows add-in and the code automatically update it. As currently if current workbook sheet 1 add new rows, I have to manually update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there's several steps to get to your desired result.

1. I'm assuming your 2nd workbook is not open yet so you need to open it in VBA first before being able to copy your ranges. There are plenty of answers on SO and google that show you how to do that.
2. Since you will be adding rows to the original worksheet you need a way to include this in your code. There's a few options on how to do that.

   You could create a table and use `Dim As ListObject` to declare and then set it in VBA. That way when new rows are added to the table they will be automatically included. A second way would be to use a dynamic named range (see name Manager under formulas tab), that includes new rows when they are added.
3. Possibly the most important part is making the code easier by declaring your variables and objects.

Currently you write `wb1.Sheets("dataform")` constantly. Instead use `Dim DataForm as Worksheet` and `Set Dataform = wb1.Sheets("dataform")`. This way when use adress your sheet you can just write `Dataform.Range("A1:A1")`. See below for an example.

```
    Dim Source As Workbook
    Set Source = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Dataform As Worksheet
    Set Dataform = Source.Sheets("Dataform")

    Dataform.Range("L2:N2").Copy 'See how you can just adress the sheet by name
```

Now if you were to also declare you ranges as tables/named ranges this would make the code even easier to process. Since you're also always adding a row during each operation a much more efficient way would be to use a `for each loop` to go through all your named ranges/tables, copy them, insert a new row into the destination sheet and then paste.

Hope this was some inspiration

Comment: Thanks for the help @Nick, I understand the concept using 'for each loop' but having trouble adding for each loop function under the "dataform.range("L2:N2").copy". I'll put the code below that I have done.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyInfo()
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    dataform.Range("L2:N2").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("A2").Rows("1:27").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("A2:C28").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    dataform.Range("LocationName").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("D2").Insert Shift:=xlDown

    dataform.Range("Reading").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("F2").Insert Shift:=xlDown

    update

    wb1.Sheets("Setlist").Range("D2").Copy

    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("E2").Rows("1:27").Insert Shift:=xlDown

   wb2.Sheets(shtname).Columns().AutoFit

Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

Sub update()   

    dataform.Range("Reading").Copy
    dataform.Range("PreviousReading, Usage").PasteSpecial

    dataform.Range("Usage").Copy
    wb2.Sheets(shtname).Range("G2").Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

**(There are more codes but I just add half of it, sorry for the confusion. If there's useful links that could help. Much appreciated.)**

Comment: As a start please use the information I gave you so far to adjust your code. So, give all your worksheets clear names so you can make the code more readable. Make sure you check how to copy data to another workbook (i.e. open and activate it before copying). Then give the ranges you want to copy some sensible names using the name manager or in VBA directly. Then you can use the [Names Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names), w/ a  `for each loop` to go through every named range, insert a new row in your new workbook and then copy from the first.